# Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory PHP?

Tags: php

I am getting this error when trying to use `mkdir()` function in PHP.

basically I am creating a sundomain on my server based on an `input field` in the HTML form named (`inPut`).

now I am trying to create a directory in that subdomain after it has been created.

so I use the following code :

```
$subDomain= $_POST['inPut'];

mkdir("$subDomain.mydoamin.com/newDirectory", 0755);
```

but I get the following error:

```
Warning: mkdir() [function.mkdir]: No such file or directory in line 99.
```

and on line 99 is this:

```
mkdir("$subDomain.mydoamin.com/newDirectory", 0755);
```

as a note: the subdomain gets created successfully. so I know the subdomain 100% does exist on my server. I just don't know why I get that error!

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try to put third parameter. The method signature is:

```
bool mkdir ( string $pathname [, int $mode = 0777 [, bool $recursive = false [, resource $context ]]] )
```

So your code would be:

```
mkdir(__DIR__ . "/$subDomain.mydoamin.com/newDirectory", 0755, true);
```

Comment: with your code I don't get the error anymore but the `newDirectory` doesn't get created! any suggestion?

Comment: Still no error but the newDirectory doesn't get created either!

Comment: What is the output of this code : `var_dump(__DIR__ . "/$subDomain.mydoamin.com/newDirectory")`

Comment: Nothing! I don't get any output from that!

Comment: Are you sure? Put that var_dump before mkdir and please recheck that you request the page correctly.

Comment: okay, sorry I made a mistake. now I am getting this output: `string(62) "/home/mySite/public_html/gdfgdfgdfg.mysite.com/newDirectory"`

Comment: this is my test by the way: `gdfgdfgdfg`... :)

Comment: that means that the newdir has been created but I cannot see it on my server! lol

Comment: What do you mean by "can not see it". What did you do to see it btw?

Comment: Just looking directly in my server and I also, tried to open the URL in the browser.

Comment: Regarding to your server, is this path correct? `/home/mySite/public_html/gdfgdfgdfg.mysite.com/newDirectory` and does your webserver have permission to write into it?

Comment: mate, it just started working and I can see the newDr's now! i swear my server's got mind of its own!

Answer (score 1):

Try this, **[EDITED]**

```
 mkdir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $subDomain . '/newDirectory', 0755);
```

Comment: won't this create the `newDirecotry` in the `root` of the domain? for example: `mydomain.com/newDirectory` ?

Comment: In which case you should try Andy's solution. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

`mkdir` is only working with the directory path, not the URL or domain.

```
mkdir('sub.domain.com/newdir'); // return false

mkdir('/public_html/subdomain/newdir'); //return true if /public_html/subdomain is exist
```

You should have to point to your subdomain's absolute path, not the URL.